# Why PHP does not have a common coding convention

Tags: php, coding-style, coding-standards

Why there is common coding convention in PHP. Just like python has pep8 .Some frameworks prefers camelcase but wordpress uses underscore while naming functions and variables which is actually preferred.

Answer (score 3):

There is something called PSR (PHP Standards Recommendations) which standardizes  PHP codes: [See this link](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/)

Wordpress was created years ago, and because of backward compatibility, it does not implement these standards. So, Wordpress is not a good example to understand current PHP standards and best practices. On the other hand, currently most of PHP frameworks are created using PSR standards.